# How has been the religious exchange among India and the West after Vivekananda's Chicago speech?

Tags: history, other-religions, vivekananda

Swami Vivekananda in his time had stated that spiritualism grew at a faster rate in India contrasting to the West, where materialism developed faster.

In his later life he had in fact been disenchanted with Hinduism he witnessed at his time and on occasion suggested a sort of "trade" between the spiritually developed India and America to mutual benefit. It was aimed or was hoped to strike a balance between the two cultures influenced by of respective religious roots when unfolding.

Nothing changed tangibly that was noticed after his Chicago address or return..

Is this true? Has any systematic work been undertaken for a two-way influence between the West and East? Or is this just a figment of imagination from a poor man's viewpoint for self-appeasement?

Comment: Good question but little unclear. Swami Vivekananda made the foundation for several other Gurus like Paramahamsa, Osho, Jaggi Vasudev & many more. Similarly we too got Sister Nivedita, Mother Teresa & Christian missionaries. At times US Indians are more religiously conservative than Indians. Similarly Indian Christians know more about Bible than average westerners. So the influence is tremendous. Is that what are you asking?

Comment: Things have changed and from a Hinduism perspective it is arguably unhealthy. The main reason is the success enjoyed by proselytisation efforts (due Missionaries) of Abrahamic Religions. One major factor is that they are currently well-funded, consequently well-organised in many places particularly in TN

Comment: @iammilind .. who is the Paramahamsa you are referring to? Before Osho. Which Paramahamsa. There are so many out there.

Comment: @ArkaprabhaMajumdar Paramahansa Yogananda.

Comment: @iammilind Not exactly. I am asking about what mentionable materialistic influence from West, India was in colonial rule, its not difficult to guess what  could be or could not be done. About influence to the West. Vivekananda was looked upon with respect and even awe however it waned. Hitler used  political claim of Aryan race etc. Yoga had spread to an extent.and so much for the interactions.

Comment: question is asking for opinions. read the forum rules...

Comment: Asking for the past facts, not any opinions.